# PayPal's Express Checkout in Magento2 doesn't work

Tags: paypal-sandbox, magento2

I would like to test PayPal's Express payment in magento 2.1.7
The server(WAMP) is local in my laptop.

First, I created a PayPal Sandbox Account to receive the payment of the orders.
[image]

Second, I set the Sandbox Account into Magento 2.
[image]

Lastly, I tried this PayPal Payment in Magento, but it doesn't work.[image]

After I click the button "Continue to Paypal", I just get a pop-up window with link "about:blank".
In 1 minute, the page come back to the Checkout page again.
[image]

I have no idea now, what happened and where could I modify.

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue...
It's not difficult.
I just disabled the option "Enable SSL verification" in the Advanced Settings of Paypal Express Payment.
Because my Magento is local and I hane not a SSL certificate...